# Should arrays of IDs stored in Postgres use varchar, int, or another type?

Tags: postgresql

What is proper convention for creating a field that will hold an array of foreign keys? In this particular case, I'm creating a field called "owners" that will hold an array of user IDs. I want to make sure I choose the right type to maximize speed and follow convention.

Thanks.

Comment: I intend to store an array of user IDs associated with owning an account. Does that need a new table?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The "one true way" is to create a table and use foreign keys:

```
CREATE TABLE owners(
    user_id int references users
  , account_id int references accounts
  , primary key(user_id, account_id)
);
```

That way you can verify membership using a single and simple query:

```
SELECT user_id, account_id FROM owners WHERE user_id = X AND account_id = Y
```

And you can get a list of owners for an account using:

```
SELECT user_id FROM owners WHERE account_id = X
```

Alternatively, you can find all accounts a user owns using the reverse query:

```
SELECT account_id FROM owners WHERE user_id = X
```

Answer (score 3):

So apparently PostgreSQL has array functionality built in! This took some extra searching, but found an article on PGSQL documentation describing how arrays can be defined for certain field types.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html

Basically, the syntax looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE sal_emp (
    name            text,
    pay_by_quarter  integer[],
    schedule        text[][]
);
```

It goes as deep to allow strict definition of array size and depth. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

SQL uses foreign key references from the perspective of the child, not the parent. So a parent does not have an array of child ids, but rather many child records that reference the same parent id.

### Has Many

If an *owner* has many *users*, this is a "has many" relationship.

```sql
// owners
create table parents (
  id uuid primary key
);

// users
create table children (
  id uuid primary key,
  parent_id references parent(id)
);
```

### Many to many

If an *owner* has many *users*,
and a *user* has many *owners*,
then this is a "many to many" relationship.

At first, you might think to do this...

```sql
// owners
create table parents (
  id uuid primary key,
  child_id references child(id)
);

// users
create table children (
  id uuid primary key,
  parent_id references parent(id)
);
```

However, that pattern should be avoided because it causes a circular dependency between the two tables. Instead, the "many to many" relationship should be done using a third table, known as a join table.

```sql
// owners
create table parents (
  id uuid primary key
);

// users
create table children (
  id uuid primary key
);

// owners_users
create table parents_children (
  parent_id references parent(id),
  child_id references child(id)
);
```

##### Benefits of Join tables

Join tables also have fewer fields which can make them faster in queries. For example the `parents` and `children` tables might have hundred fields each, and `parent_children` table would only have the two reference fields.

```sql
create table parents (
  id uuid,

  -- n = 100 fields
  field1 varchar,
  field2 varchar,
  field3 varchar,
  -- etc...
  field100 varchar
);

create table children (
  id uuid,

  -- n = 100 fields
  field1 varchar,
  field2 varchar,
  field3 varchar,
  -- etc...
  field100 varchar
);

create table parents_children (

  -- n = 2 fields
  parent_id uuid references parent,
  child_id uuid references child,

  primary key(parent_id, child_id)
);
```